# Where to get a large list of safe-for-work domain names?

Tags: testing, networking, dns

Does anyone know where I could find a list of safe-for-work (i.e. no porn, piracy sites, etc) domain names that I can use to stress test software that performs asynchronous DNS lookups without raising questions if my network admin happens to be watching?

At least several thousand would be ideal.  Most lists I've found have not been filtered at all.  So far, using "raw" lists for DNS queries have not raised any questions, but my next step is to create TCP connections.

**EDIT:**  I've cleared everything with local network admin people, however, this would still be nice to have for future developers on the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network admin will probably be more concerned with the fact that you're stress testing a network service on his network on the order of thousands of domains. If you have any kind of decent corporate firewall it's inspecting DNS queries and could choke on a high rate of queries. If your requirement is a legitimate business requirement the best option is to have your boss talk to the head of the network department to CYA.

Comment: Already did check with my network admin w/ regarding to potentially DOS-ing the DNS server.  Aside from the possibility that I'm wiping out anything useful in its cache, the DNS server holds up just fine.  But eventually this test is likely be passed on to other developers in another office.  It would be nice if they could run it without the risk of raising questions.

Comment: .edu or .gov domains are usually safe. You can find zone files out there on the internet for the TLDs. I would try that. http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html

Comment: Good thinking on .gov & .edu.  [Here](https://explore.data.gov/Federal-Government-Finances-and-Employment/Federal-Executive-Branch-Internet-Domains/k9h8-e98h) is a list of .gov sites downloadable in several file formats, and [here](http://doors.stanford.edu/universities.html) is a big list of .edu's.  About 2500 in total.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably worry too much. Having said that how about doing a google search for '[interesting facts about butterflies](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB442GB442&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=interesting%20facts%20about%20butterflies)', parsing all the resulting domains and using those?